# Laravel 4 - How to use 'offset' in stead of 'page' with Eloquent's ->paginate()?

Tags: php, pagination, laravel, laravel-4

I am migrating an existing REST API to Laravel 4.1, and the API currently uses **`offset`** as querystring parameter to specify what the *offset* of the records needs to be.

I would like to use the default Eloquent's `paginate()`, but these searches for the **`page`** querystring parameter. And of course it uses the page number (like 2) instead of the offset (like 200).

Is there an easy way to configure the `paginate` function to this situation? Or do I need to use `->skip()` and `->take()` functions and make the links to the next page myself?

@Anam: I want to use:

```
$warehouses = Warehouse::orderBy('name')
    ->paginate($perpage);
```

This works with http://example.org/api/warehouses?page=2, but I want this to work with http://example.org/api/warehouses?offset=200

With the offset I can use:

```
$warehouses = Warehouse::orderBy('name')
    ->skip($offset)
    ->take($perpage)
    ->get();
```

But then I cannot use the same controller for the API and the web view. So I would prefer some way to make the first one working.

Comment: Can you share some example code?

Comment: Just put $perpage = Input::get('perpage');
And throw in a ?perpage=200 in the url  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But then I cannot use the same controller for the API and the web view. So I would prefer some way to make the first one working.

Why not? If you already know `?offset` will be available in the API, and `?page` in your normal view. Just detect which is found and apply it appropriately.

---

That said, you can retrieve the paginator environment instance the query builder uses and pass it a page number that you define.

```
$perPage = 50;
$currentPage = 1;

if ($offset = Input::get('offset'))
{
    $currentPage = ($offset / $perPage);
}

Warehouse::resolveConnection()->getPaginator()->setCurrentPage($currentPage);

$warehouses = Warehouse::orderBy('name')->paginate($perpage);
```

Note that, while I tested this and it works, I don't know how much it will affect other queries that you might run on the same page. Look into it, use with caution.

Comment: Thanks. I hoped there was a cleaner solution, but I will use this for now.

Comment: I think no matter the solution, you'd have to overwrite the paginator instance used by that particular Eloquent model, and that's how you'd retrieve it (to the best of my knowledge). Otherwise you'd be globally overwriting all instances, and that could mess with your code in other places.

Comment: Frankly, if a solution has just a few lines of code, that's pretty clean to me. ;)

Comment: For Laravel 5 I think it is no longer working. Did not find a getPaginator() function. The paginate() function on the builder is returning a new Paginator  each invocation. Currently I found how to change globally the request variable name in the PaginationServiceProvider.

Comment: @elpd I would have to check what the implementation for L5 would be. I'm not familiar with every small change made, and how the above would be accomplished differently. I do know that you can use middleware to add in additional request data if you needed, though. Could probably do that and avoid needing to modify your model's connections or paginators entirely.