# How to paginate data Laravel and Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I am having a little problem using Laravel pagination with Ajax. I sucessfully fetch the first 10 data but can't fetch the next 10 and so on.

Below is my code

```
 public function FetchClassList()
{   
    $user_id = Input::get("user_id");
    $offset = Input::get("offset", 0);
    $limit = 10;


        $class_list = DB::table('users')
                ->leftJoin('profiles', 'users.user_id', '=', 'profiles.user_id')
                ->select('user_sname','user_fname','users.user_id','user_uname')
                ->where('users.userid','!=',$user_id)
                ->orderBy('users.user_sname')
                ->skip($offset)->take($limit)->get();

        $totalItems = DB::table('users')
                ->leftJoin('profiles', 'users.user_id', '=', 'profiles.user_id')
                ->where('users.user_id','!=',$usere_id)->count();

        $class_list = Paginator::make($class_list, $totalItems, $limit);

        return Response::json(($class_list));

}
```

From the code, it returns `total,per_page,current_page,last_page,from,to`, which of them do I return to the server to get the next 10 data?

Comment: Show us your ajax and the reponse data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try increasing the value of the offset variable in a dynamic way

`$offset = Input::get("offset", 0);`

because It is initialized to zero statically. Pseudo-code:

```
$offset = ($page * $per_page) - $per_page;
```

The [following link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20759969/laravel-4-how-to-use-offset-in-stead-of-page-with-eloquents-paginate) is a related question.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have already done that but the returned `current_page` does not increase. How can I keep track of which page I am?

Comment: You can add to the query string of pagination links using the appends method on the Paginator. This will generate URLs that look something like this: http://example.com/something?page=2&sort=votes, then you can monitor the current page capturing the page parameter.